# Getting error when accessing a sheet in Google Drive through API

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm using the spreadsheet v3 API [https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/data#update_multiple_cells_with_a_batch_request] to update some cells in a row of specific worksheet. It works most of the time, but I'm also getting the following error.

> Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again.

I'm not able to find out when and why this error occurs but it happens to be a showstopper. Any help on why this error may occur?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this solution:

> Regarding your issue, I have some basic troubleshooting steps to
> consider:
>
> - Sign out of your Google account and sign back in
> - If applicable, delete the Google app(s) and reinstall again
> - Make sure your computer's operating system is running the latest version
> - Restart your computer
> - Try replicating your issue on another browser

Source: [Error on Google Drive: Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/GGGF5AzKwdE).

As mentioned in this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/pR2aclr4Swc), this can be a problem if you're not the owner of the file.

**Additional note:**

As mentioned in this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/pR2aclr4Swc), this can be a problem if you're not the owner of the file.

Try making a copy of the file and see if you can access it.